# Swift 3 what means FileManager.default(......).first?

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

```
guard let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for:
FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in:
FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first
```

I don't understand what means here first? Is it in documentation?

Comment: You can simplify this a bit: `guard let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { ... }`

Comment: `first` is the same thing as `arr[0]` indexing from the `first index` from any array

Comment: ... except `first` returns an optional, and the subscript operator with an index of zero doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The [`urls`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407726-urls) method returns an [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) of [`URL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) objects. The [`first`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689165-first) method retrieves the first item in a Swift `Array`.

For more information, see the [documentation for `first`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689165-first).